# How to Log Newly-Created Users into the Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have looked and so far not been able to find the answer. When a user creates a new account i want the user to be automatically logged into the site as opposed to just being redirected to the log in page. I am able to create the users but am unsuccessful at finding logging them in.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using forms authentication, you can create the authorization cookie using the [SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx) method like this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Text, false);
```